# Why the signal handler doesn't process the signal

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm trying to make a program that simulates the command nohup. The program gets as a first parameter, the name of a command that is gonna be executed.
The program executed by my program must not be notified when the terminal is closed, it will have to ignore the SIGHUP.
If I test my program with with the following command:

```
         ./mynohup sleep 120 &
```

And then I try to send a SIGHUP from another terminal, sleep terminates when it should be immune to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "utils.h"

#define NOHUP_OUT_FILE      "nohup.out"

static void handle_signal(int signum)
{
    if(signum == SIGHUP)
    {
        printf("This is ignored\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not ignored\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

/* configure handlers */
static void set_signals(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    int rc;

    /* TODO - ignore SIGHUP */
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = handle_signal;
    rc = sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);

    DIE(rc == -1, "sigaction");

}

/* execute a new program */
static void exec_func(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc;
    int i;
    char **exec_args;
    int fd;

    set_signals();  /* ignore SIGHUP */

    if(isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
        fd = open(NOHUP_OUT_FILE, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
        DIE(fd < 0, "open");

        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd);
    }

    /* exec a new process */
    exec_args = malloc(argc * sizeof(*exec_args));
    DIE(exec_args == NULL, "malloc");

    for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++)
        exec_args[i] = argv[i+1];
    exec_args[argc-1] = NULL;

    execvp(exec_args[0], exec_args);
    DIE(1, "execvp");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command_and_arguments\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exec_func(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to skip creating a new process and the signal handler works great.
If the signal handler is in the following form the program works

```
static void set_signals(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    int rc;

    /* ignore SIGHUP */
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;

    rc = sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
    DIE(rc == -1, "sigaction");
}
```

I don't understand why when I create the first version of the signal handler the program doesn't works and with the second one it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not safe to use stdio functions in signal handlers, btw. [man signal-safety](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All exec functions reset the dispositions of caught signals to their default dispositions.

When you exec, your process image is destroyed and replaced by the process image of the new program. In it, the pointer to the `handle_function` you passed to sigaction no longer has meaning, or the old meaning at least. The only sensible thing the OS can do with handled signals upon `execve` is to reset them.

The meaning of `SIG_IGN` is universal and independent of the current program and that's why `SIG_IGN` can be, and is, inherited.

Comment: But that's not an answer to the question.  Effectively, you cannot install a signal handler, but you have to do something for the process not to receive signals, as it will be killed by the kernel on session hungup.  You have to add to your question that the process must create a new process group and get separate from the job managing the shell does, or it will die anyway.

Comment: @LuisColorado Ignoring the SIGHUP before execing correctly does the job. The OP already found that out. Creating a new process group is unnecessary. The question was why the SIG_IGN approach works but using installing a handler doesn't.

Comment: @PSkockik, no problem for `SIGHUP`, `SIGINTR` and `SIGQUIT`, but indeed it is a problem for the unmaskable, unignorable `SIGSTOP` signal.  It is necessary to create a new process group and dissasociate the control terminal from the process, or it can be assigned the terminal by other process in the job control (mainly the shell) and begin receiving terminal signals again.

Comment: What about programs that decide to set the `SIGHUP` to default, when you execute them from that program?  They will be killed, which is not the purpose of `nohup(1)` program.

Comment: @LuisColorado Starting a new process group won't prevent `SIGSTOP` deliveries either (only `SIGTSTOP`). In any case, OP's just trying to emulate `nohup`  (according to the question) and pretty much all `nohup` does as far as signals are concerned is ignore `SIGHUP` (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/nohup.c;h=53fdaf941af9c98a346627ecb1a820c573e330ea;hb=HEAD)

Comment: Well, `nohup(1)` accepts programs that set `SIGHUP` to default... so how does it manage?

Comment: @LuisColorado It doesn't.

Comment: @LuisColorado It might be just fine (presumably a program resetting it's SIGHUP disposition wishes to open itself up to the possibility of dying from terminal hangups) or it might be insufficient for your use case, but regardless of that, `nohup` is POSIX-standardized (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) in terms of ignoring `SIGHUP`. It shouldn't be doing anything with process groups or the controlling terminal.

Answer (score 2):

`execvp()` is a front end for the `execve()` syscall.

From [its linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the following:
>
> ```
>   *  The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset to
>       the default (signal(7)).
> ```

So the signal handler you installed is reset.

Answer (score 0):

## CORRECTION: (see history of changes for original text)

The `nohup(1)` program just shifts the progran name (`nohup`) and the options to it, from the `argc`/`argv` parameters to `main`, redirects `stdout`/`stderr` to a file (`nohup.out`) in case one or both are directed to a tty device, and then just ignores `SIGHUP` and `execvp(*argv, argv);` for the original program to execute.  It even does no `fork(2)` at all.

The source code of FreeBSD nohup is available [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/nohup/nohup.c).